# Constructing a promise without a resolver or reject

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a asynchronous function `sayHello()` which is called inside `greeting()` function:

```
function greeting() {
    let P = new Promise();
    sayHello().then(function(){
       //manipulate DOM 
       P.resolve();
    }).catch(function(error)){
       //manipulate DOM 
       P.reject();
    });
    return P;
}
```

I want `greeting()` to return a promise, so the caller would know when `sayHello`'s work  is finished. But this code doesn't seem to be correct, as it says Promise should have `resolve` and `reject` functions defined when being constructed. What should I do ?

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, return your promise chain directly.  If you already have promises, you never need `new Promise()`.

Comment: I don't want to manipulate the DOM in the caller of greeting, I want to do it inside greeting.

Comment: That doesn't change anything.  You can still return a promise chain.

Comment: can you post a code ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh What do you mean? `return sayHello()`. Is `.then()` chained to `greeting()` call expecting a value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return the `Promise` returned by `sayHello()`:

```
function greeting() {
  return sayHello().then(function(){
    //manipulate DOM 
  }).catch(function(error)){
    //manipulate DOM 
  });
}
```

The [`then` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) return a Promise.
Here's a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28hawob8/) illustrating this.

Comment: `greeting` outputs a promise (which in result, caller of `greeting` can use it and call `then` on it). So, `then` always return a promise ? even if we don't `return` anything in it ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh Yes, `.then()` returns a new `Promise` object

Comment: Important to also explain that if you have a `.catch()` handler that does not re-throw or return a rejected promise that the returned promise will be switched to the resolved state (just like if a catch block in a try/catch prevents the exception from propagating upwards.  So, what you show would not ever tell the caller of greeting that `sayHello()` failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function greeting() {
  let response
  try {
    response = await sayHello()
  } catch(err) {
    response = err
  }
  return response
}

greeting().then(response => console.log(response))

function greeting2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sayHello().then(_ => {
      //manipulate DOM
      resolve()
    }).catch(err => {
      //manipulate DOM 
      reject()
    })
  })
}

greeting2().then(_ => console.log('something'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers offer good solutions, but the actual reason you are seeing the error: *Promise should have resolve and reject functions defined when being constructed.* is the specific `Promise` implementation you are using. The latest version expects an "executor" function as the first argument when calling it:

```
new Promise(/* this is the executor: */ function (resolve, reject) { ... });
```

You can see the specification here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Older versions of `Promise` did not follow the same specification.